# CSS animation crashes Safari on iPad only

Tags: css, ios, mobile-safari, css-animations

My site crashes in Safari on iPad and on iPad only. I am animating a large picture (4800 x 374px, though only 336 kb) in the header with a css3 animation. After some ten seconds, this causes Safari to crash.

You can see the site at http://bakabaka.nl/preview/leuk/

Can I prevent this crash, and if so, how? Can I make the animation run smoother? It's very jagged now...

Comment: might be useful to add that I'm using WordPress to run this site, but I don't really see how that would influence things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but maybe worth it.

What I would try is to use a 3D animation on iOS as it uses hardware acceleration:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(X,Y,Z);
```

See here for more information: '[3D Transform Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#three-d-transform-functions)'

Also there can occur some problems with very large images on iOS. Maybe it would a better solution to cut them into pieces. Read more about it: "[Know iOS Resource Limits](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15)"

Comment: That worked like a charm. I ended up using a translateX animation just for webkit (independent from the OS) and that solved matters. Thanks!

Comment: Looks pretty sleek on my iPhone now. I'm glad to help. :)

Comment: Be careful, I actually fixed my own css transition problem by removing that line rather than adding it. No clue as to why it worked.

Comment: It depends. If you use this CSS rule heavily on many elements it can force safari to slow down or even crash. But it's perfectly good in a case like this, where you simply animate something from left to right, as it benefits from the hardware acceleration. So, without actually seeing your code, it's hard to tell, what caused your code not to work.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing something similar as well. For anyone else that might be banging their head against a wall, this was crashing Safari on both desktop and iOS. It *really* doesn't like that `::window-inactive` selector.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
     background: #f2f2f2; 
}
```